# PIXI.JS - Gradually Remove Slot Game Reels

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I'm in the process learning to code a slot game, I have the below code which handles the spinning of the game. I want to add a border to the reels and have the sprites gradually disappear behind the border before they are removed and returned to the top.

function spingame(){

```
spin.interactive = false;

if (reelcount === 2){
    if((reel[0].y >= 10) && (reel[5].y >= 400) && (reel[10].y >= renderer.height / 790)){

        cancelAnimationFrame(spingame);
        reelcount = 0;
        console.log(reelarray);
        checkwinnings();
        balanceUpdate();
        spin.interactive = true;
        refresh();
    }
    else{
        for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++){
            reel[i].y += anispeed;
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(spingame);
        refresh();
    }
}

else if (reel[0].y >= 790) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(spingame);
        rowNo = 5;
        reelSet();
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            reel[i].y = 10;
        }
        refresh();
        spingame();
        reelcount = reelcount + 1;
    }
    else if (reel[5].y >= 790) {
            cancelAnimationFrame(spingame);
            rowNo = 10;
            reelSet();
            for (var i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
                reel[i].y = 10;
            }
            refresh();
            spingame();
        }
        else if (reel[10].y >= 790) {
                cancelAnimationFrame(spingame);
                rowNo = 15;
                reelSet();
                for (var i = 10; i < 15; i++) {
                    reel[i].y = 10;
                }
                refresh();
                spingame();
            }

    else{
            for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                reel[i].setTexture(symb[reelarray[i]]);

                reel[i].y += anispeed;
            }
            requestAnimationFrame(spingame);
            refresh();
        }
```

What should I be looking for?

I've tried making the Sprites a child of the border but they're still visible when they move outside of the border.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was looking in the wrong place. Assign a mask to a rectangle in the center of the screen and it's now working

```
var masksContainer = new PIXI.Container();
stage.addChild(masksContainer);
var mask = new PIXI.Graphics();
mask.beginFill(0xffffff);
mask.drawRect(renderer.width / 6 , renderer.height / 7, renderer.width / 1.6 , renderer.height / 1.3);
mask.endFill();
masksContainer.addChild(mask);

for (var i = 0 ; i < 15; i++){
    masksContainer.addChild(reel[i]);
    reel[i].mask = mask;
    refresh();
}
```